# awk - skip lines of subdomains if domain already matched

Tags: bash, awk

lets assume - there is an already ordered list of domains like:

```
tld.aa.
tld.aa.do.notshowup.0
tld.aa.do.notshowup.0.1
tld.aa.do.notshowup.0.1.1
tld.aa.do.notshowup.too
tld.bb.showup
tld.aaaaa.showup
tld.xxxxx.
tld.xxxxx.donotshowup
tld.yougettheidea.dontyou
tld.yougettheidea.dontyou.thankyou
```

which later acts as a blacklist.

Per specific requirement - all lines with a trailing '.' indicate
that all deeper subdomains of that specific domain should not appear
in the blacklist itself then... so the desired output of the example
above would/should be:

```
tld.aa.
tld.bb.showup
tld.aaaaa.showup
tld.xxxxx.
tld.yougettheidea.dontyou
tld.yougettheidea.dontyou.thankyou
```

I currently run this in a loop (pure bash + heavy use of bash builtins to speedup things) ... but as the list
grows it takes quite long now to process around 562k entries.

Shouldn't it be easy for AWK (or sed maybe) to do this - any help is
really appreciated (I already tried some things in awk but somehow couldn't get it to display what I want...).

Thankyou!

Comment: Is it already sorted ?

Comment: @CorentinLimier "[...]there is an already ordered list of domains like:"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `.` lines always come before the lines to ignore, this awk should do:

```
$ awk '{for (i in a) if (index($0,i) == 1) next}/\.$/{a[$0]=1}1' file
tld.aa.
tld.bb.showup
tld.aaaaa.showup
tld.xxxxx.
tld.yougettheidea.dontyou
tld.yougettheidea.dontyou.thankyou
```

- `/\.$/{a[$0]=1}` adds lines with trailing dot to an array.
- `{for (i in a) if (index($0,i) == 1) next}` searches for the current line in one of these indexed entries and skips further processing if found (`next`).

If the file is sorted alphabetically and no subdomains end with a dot, you don't even need an array as @Corentin Limier suggests:

```
awk 'a{if (index($0,a) == 1) next}/\.$/{a=$0}1' file
```

Comment: If file is sorted, you do not need to keep all values into the array. Something like this should work and be efficient :  awk '{if(index($0,a)==1 && a!=""){next}}/\.$/{a=$0}1' file

Comment: Great - thankyou - this was exactly what I was looking for... and it's so incredible fast (it runs through 562k lines in about 2-3 seconds).